# I want to access my Moodle courses details using ASP.NET web application through moodle authentication APIs.How to do that?

Tags: php, .net, moodle

I want to access my Moodle courses details using ASP.NET web application through  moodle authentication APIs.How to do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll need to set up web services in Moodle. Choosing which functions to be available externally. Then use a protocol like REST to retrieve the data.

Here is a client example:

https://docs.moodle.org/dev/Creating_a_web_service_client

Here is how to set up web services:

https://docs.moodle.org/38/en/Using_web_services

This is the main page for web services:

https://docs.moodle.org/38/en/Web_services